# Include HTML elements in LaTeX

Tags: graphics, html

We try to include some HTML elements into a LaTeX document. 
We have a project where some complicated HTML elements are generated like the one in the picture below.
[image: HTML element]

The yellow rectangles are overlayed on a svg image with JavaScript.
Now we want to include these images into a LaTeX document. It is not possible to generate/export them manually as there are thousands of images like this one.

I tried to find a solution where i can add HTML code to LaTeX but could not find something.

The HTML code for the above image could look similar to this:

```html
<div class="topo-row mode-area-parent">
<span class="offset"><a id="t1441499130"></a></span>
<div class="sticky-holder" data-sticky-max-el="">
    <div class="sticky-header">
        <div class="phototopo" data-auto-zoom="true" data-tid="1441499130" data-width="650" data-height="279" data-view-scale="1.18181818181818" style="max-width: 650px" data-topodata="<!-- some json data -->">
            <div class="canvas autozoom animate" style="padding-bottom: 42.9231%; transform-origin: 80.0985% 12.6168% 0px; z-index: auto; transform: scale(1);">
                <img class="fixedheightmedium" src="<!-- image path -->">
                <svg class="topooverlay" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 650 279" style="display: block;">
                    <g class="areas">
                        <g class="normal">
                            <rect class="bg  " x="480.5" y="68.5" width="82" height="14"></rect>
                            <path class="areashadow  " d="M481.5 166.5L481.5 81.5L561.5 81.5L561.5 166.5Z"></path>
                            <rect class="bg  " x="359.5" y="68.5" width="95" height="14"></rect>
                            <path class="areashadow  " d="M360.5 166.5L360.5 81.5L453.5 81.5L453.5 166.5Z"></path>
                            <rect class="bg  " x="253.5" y="68.5" width="104" height="14"></rect>
                            <path class="areashadow  " d="M254.5 166.5L254.5 81.5L356.5 81.5L356.5 166.5Z"></path>
                            <rect class="bg  " x="126.5" y="68.5" width="119" height="14"></rect>
                            <path class="areashadow  " d="M127.5 166.5L127.5 81.5L244.5 81.5L244.5 166.5Z"></path>
                            <rect class="fg  " x="127" y="69" width="118" height="13"></rect>
                            <rect class="fg  " x="254" y="69" width="103" height="13"></rect>
                            <rect class="fg  " x="360" y="69" width="94" height="13"></rect>
                            <rect class="fg  " x="481" y="69" width="81" height="13"></rect>
                        </g>
                        <g class="normal">
                            <path class="area  " d="M127.5 166.5L127.5 81.5L244.5 81.5L244.5 166.5Z"></path>
                            <text class=" " x="156.796875" y="79.734375">Central Park</text>
                            <path class="area  " d="M254.5 166.5L254.5 81.5L356.5 81.5L356.5 166.5Z"></path>
                            <text class=" " x="289.4609375" y="79.734375">Obras Selectas</text>
                            <path class="area  " d="M360.5 166.5L360.5 81.5L453.5 81.5L453.5 166.5Z"></path>
                            <text class=" " x="400.921875" y="79.796875">Sombra Perpetua</text>
                            <path class="area  " d="M481.5 166.5L481.5 81.5L561.5 81.5L561.5 166.5Z"></path>
                            <text class=" " x="505.3203125" y="79.796875">El paraíso</text>
                        </g>
                        <g class="selected"></g>
                        <g class="selected"></g>
                        <g class="hover"></g>
                        <g class="hover"></g>
                    </g>
                    <g class="render">
                        <g class="routes"></g>
                        <g class="zindex4"></g>
                        <g class="labels"></g>
                        <defs>
                            <pattern id="diagonalHatch" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10">
                                <line x1="-5" y1="0" x2="10" y2="15" stroke="#08c" stroke-width="3" stroke-opacity="70%"></line>
                                <line x1="0" y1="-5" x2="15" y2="10" stroke="#08c" stroke-width="3" stroke-opacity="70%"></line>
                            </pattern>
                        </defs>
                    </g>
                    <g class="events">
                        <path class="area shape" d="M127.5 166.5L127.5 81.5L244.5 81.5L244.5 166.5Z" data-nid="587217471"></path>
                        <rect class="area label" x="126.5" y="67.5" width="119" height="15" data-nid="587217471"></rect>
                        <path class="area shape" d="M254.5 166.5L254.5 81.5L356.5 81.5L356.5 166.5Z" data-nid="587225973"></path>
                        <rect class="area label" x="253.5" y="67.5" width="104" height="15" data-nid="587225973"></rect>
                        <path class="area shape" d="M360.5 166.5L360.5 81.5L453.5 81.5L453.5 166.5Z" data-nid="587233428"></path>
                        <rect class="area label" x="359.5" y="67.5" width="95" height="15" data-nid="587233428"></rect>
                        <path class="area shape" d="M481.5 166.5L481.5 81.5L561.5 81.5L561.5 166.5Z" data-nid="843824724"></path>
                        <rect class="area label" x="480.5" y="67.5" width="82" height="15" data-nid="843824724"></rect>
                    </g>
                </svg>
            </div><!-- .canvas -->
        </div><!-- .phototopo -->
    </div>
</div>
```

the code for this images is not from us, so I do not know how exactly this works.
We just need to add these kind of images into a LaTeX document including the yellow rectangles.

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions!

Comment: Would it be possible to generate a PDF for example from the HTML? This could then be included in a LaTeX document with `\includegraphics`.